# Create a Google Widget in AASP

Tags: widget, android-source

I am trying to create a Google Widget App in AASP(AOSP, Android), The APPWIDGET_SERVICE was disabled in frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/SystemServer.java file due to Automotive restrictions, But as per my requirement i needed to enable and i have did it successfully and able to get instance of AppWidgetManager. But, still i am not able to use other methods of AppWidgetManager like isRequestPinAppWidgetSupported() which can be helpful to create Google Widget. Any reference or guidance will be appreciated.